Ubuntu-Mate Encrypted Drive (READ ONLY)..I REALLY MESSED UP
I am REALLY HOPING FOR SOME EXPERT ADVICE....
Somehow I really messed up..my Main UBUNTU MATE ENCRYPTED DRIVE went (READ ONLY)
I can still see my files are intact on the drive

I loaded up another drive with UBUNTU MATE (NO ENCRYPTION) and as you can see I am able to enter my PASSWORD and UNLOCK the PARTITION
I am not sure how to proceed from here and turn to you EXPERTS to give me the advice if possible so I can RECOVER my DATA on that PARTITION.



